# How do I format datetime argument labels?

Tags: devexpress, devextreme

I'm trying to make a chart with the datetime argument labels formatted as `MMM yyyy`, e.g. Mar 2017. However, when I try to format in the same way as the documentation (even trying the [example given](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/15_2/Guide/Data_Visualization/Common/Data_Formatting/#Format_Text) - `MM/d`), the argument axis labels disappear.

Here is what I've noticed, from trying various formats (examples are all based on 10 March 2017):

- Removing format works fine, but labels show the default format
- `MMM yyyy` - labels disappear
- `M` - month labels show correctly (e.g. 3)
- `MM` - labels all show '00'
- `MMM` - labels disappear
- `MMMM` - labels disappear
- `y` - labels show correct year (e.g. 2017)
- `yy` - labels show correctly (e.g. 17)
- `yyyy` - labels disappear
- `MMMM y` - labels show (e.g. March 2017)
- `M y` - labels disappear
- `MM y` - labels disappear
- `MMM y` - labels disappear
- `MMMM-y` - labels disappear

My code:

HTML:

```
<div id="spline-chart"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function($) {
    $("#spline-chart").dxChart({
        series: [{
            argumentField: "Date",
            type: "spline",
            valueField: "Spend",
            name: "Spend"
        }],
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true
        },
        dataSource: {
            store: new DevExpress.data.ArrayStore({
                data: [
                    { Date: "2016-11-25", Spend: 142 },
                    { Date: "2016-12-02", Spend: 562 },
                    { Date: "2016-12-09", Spend: 425 },
                    { Date: "2016-12-16", Spend: 449 },
                    { Date: "2016-12-23", Spend: 239 },
                    { Date: "2016-12-30", Spend: 121 },
                    { Date: "2017-01-06", Spend: 322 },
                    { Date: "2017-01-13", Spend: 427 },
                    { Date: "2017-01-20", Spend: 196 },
                    { Date: "2017-01-27", Spend: 201 },
                    { Date: "2017-02-03", Spend: 256 },
                    { Date: "2017-02-10", Spend: 399 },
                    { Date: "2017-02-17", Spend: 403 },
                    { Date: "2017-02-24", Spend: 432 },
                    { Date: "2017-03-03", Spend: 239 },
                    { Date: "2017-03-10", Spend: 127 },
                    { Date: "2017-03-17", Spend: 508 },
                    { Date: "2017-03-24", Spend: 514 },
                    { Date: "2017-03-31", Spend: 338 },
                    { Date: "2017-04-07", Spend: 184 }
                ]
            })
        },
        argumentAxis: {
            grid: { "visible": true },
            minorGrid: { "visible": true },
            argumentType: "datetime",
            tickInterval: { months: 1 },
            label: {
                format: "MMM yyyy"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[Here's the codepen link](https://codepen.io/dagre/pen/WppzKr).

How can I format the axis to 'Mar 2017'?

Comment: According to https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/15_2/Guide/Data_Visualization/Common/Data_Formatting/#Available_Formats/Date-Time_Formats maybe you should use `monthAndYear`

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk The `monthAndYear` format includes the long month name, whereas I would like the short month name (e.g. 'Mar 2017' instead of 'March 2017'). Plus, I would like to understand custom date formats anyway, as I'll likely want different formats in the future. Thanks anyway.

Comment: While you find a solution, as a temporary workaround, maybe you can use this solution https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T131424 and use a javascript function to format the date. (Documented here: https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/Guide/Widgets/Common/Data_Visualization_Widgets/Data_Formatting/#Custom_Format)

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk Thanks for the tip. I'll take a look at it as a workaround, but I'd really like to know why the DevExpress methods are not working as expected.